# CORS issues while accessing https REST end point

Tags: rest, https, cors

I want to consume a REST resource available at http://localhost:9080/StudentWeb/MyRest-rest/services/students/
from my AngularJS app, and the REST application is deployed in Websphere Appliation Server with following deployment descriptor (web.xml). And application is working perfect with this configuration, with users in RegisteredUsers role.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>MyRestApplicationServicesWeb</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
            JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
        <servlet-name>MyRestRest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myrest.student.rest.StudentApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyRestRest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyRest-rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-role>
        <description>RegisteredUsers</description>
        <role-name>RegisteredUsers</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Area for authenticated users</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/MyRest-rest/services/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>RegisteredUsers</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myrest.student.filter.StudentCORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyRest-rest/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I want secure the data flow between the AngularJS app and WAS REST endpoint, by adding converting REST API to https. For that added,

```
<user-data-constraint>
    <description>Redirects http requests to https</description>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

in the security-constraint tag.

And please find the CORS filter added,

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Inside Filter");

        ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Method", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

        String accessControlReqHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        System.out.println(accessControlReqHeader);

        if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", accessControlReqHeader);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

But now getting error on AngularJS app as follows,

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9080/StudentWeb/MyRest-rest/services/students/12341234. The request was redirected to 'https://localhost:9443/StudentWeb/MyRest-rest/services/students/12341234', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

I can see this as a CORS issue for https. How can I get around with this issue.

Comment: How is your configuration for URL rewrite for requests to index.html page for angularjs routes. My application was breaking here other than CORS error which now I fixed for accept headers as *? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem, or at least one of them.

((HttpServletResponse) response).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

You can't use the wildcard when sending credentials with a CORS request.  Instead explicitly list the origin.  If you will have many, inspect the origin header from the client and if your server decides to serve content to that client then return the content of the request origin header as the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.